# FFmpeg Centos Compile Error - caused by libwebp (error: implicit declaration of function ‘libwebp_error_to_averror’)

Tags: ffmpeg, webp

I'm trying to compile FFmpeg on Centos 7.9. I followed the official instructions: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos

I need support for WebP images, so I installed `libwebp` and `libwebp-devel` via YUM, and used the option `--enable-libwebp`.

But at the ffmepg "make" stage, the following error is returned:

```
CC      libavcodec/libwebpenc_common.o
libavcodec/libwebpenc_common.c: In function ‘ff_libwebp_get_frame’:
libavcodec/libwebpenc_common.c:283:17: error: implicit declaration of function ‘libwebp_error_to_averror’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
                 ret = libwebp_error_to_averror(pic->error_code);
                 ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [libavcodec/libwebpenc_common.o] Error 1
```

Does anyone know why this error is occuring and how it can be corrected?

I've tried compiling without using `--enable-libwebp` and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change libwebp_error_to_averror to ff_libwebp_error_to_averror

Answer (score 0):

edit libavcodec/libwebpenc_common.c:283, replace libwebp_error_to_averror with ff_libwebp_error_to_averror

Comment: This is the same as the other answer